# ThreeJS - delineate between meshes

Tags: three.js, shader, mesh, post-processing

I am displaying a number of different models simultaneously in three.

Some models have the same texture, and it can make it hard to tell where one starts and another ends.

As an example, first image is from my three viewer, second image is from Blender:

[image]

[image]

It is not obvious in three where the two objects intersect.

I've so far attempted to alter lighting and material settings but have been without success on that front.

I also tried an outline post processing effect but due to what I think is a disorderly output from Sketchup (where the models were made) the outline effect is chaotic:

[image]

I am trying to find a good way to clearly delineate between models.

Comment: You may have some luck reading [through this forum conversation](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/ldraw-like-edges/17100). There are some good demos of how to achieve that effect there.

Comment: Here's an approach to create conditional lines, built by Garrett Johnson: https://github.com/gkjohnson/threejs-sandbox/tree/master/conditional-lines

Answer (score 0):

Raycaster from mouse position. De-emphasize the other models' opacity or something. Or if you're serious, you could try the clipping stencil. There's some really good examples for mesh BVH that demonstrates this. https://gkjohnson.github.io/three-mesh-bvh/example/bundle/clippedEdges.html